# How to remove my whitespace between h1 and h2 or how to get it to what i want

Tags: html, css

[Current design that it is showing as in webbrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFNYh.png)

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRFPU.png)

Hi Team,

I am trying to design my header for my website and I want to remove the white space between the H1 and H2 so that it all looks like one item - as I will be doing different font for each heading. Below is my HTML and CSS. I have tried to use margins and paddings but that did not seem to work - any help please.

Thank You

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.header {
  width:1200px;
  position: relative;
}
  .header img {
    float: left;
}
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #666600;
}
.header h2 {
    font-size: 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #666600;
}
```

```html
 <body>
   <div class="header">
    <img src="https://kapaifuel.neocities.org/Resources/KaPaiLogo.png" alt="KaPaiLogo" />
    <h1>KA PAI FUEL CAFÉ </h1> 
    <h2>Whangaihia to tinana ki te kai / Nourish you body with organic kai</h2>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-heigth: 1` to this code

```
.header .H1, .H2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I have added another question below so I can show you, can you advise to that as well if you know how to remove the white area around so that there is no white space on my header and navigation bar i.e the white space around the top and left and right - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use label or span whatever your choice. that is becuase "h" tag elements are block element by nature. they have a big line height between them.

```css
   body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
  }
  .header {
    width:1200px;
    position: relative;
    background:#666600;
  }
    .header img {
      float: left;
  }
  .header .label1, .label2 {
        font-size: 35px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .header .label2 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
   <body>
     <div class="header">
      <img src="https://kapaifuel.neocities.org/Resources/KaPaiLogo.png" alt="KaPaiLogo" />
      <label class="label1">KA PAI FUEL CAFÉ </label> <br>
      <label class="label2">Whangaihia to tinana ki te kai / Nourish you body with organic kai</label>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you - I have tried what you suggested (now using the font I planned to use) and still not getting the result I am after - also to note that I need the Green background to go right across the screen (not just around the text)- i have added another post below to show you

Comment: @Chrissy so, you want that ? then apply the backgroundcolor of the label to header then remove the background color of the labels. i already edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the background colour but I still have the massive space between the first label and the second label - unsure how to remove it (i have updated my code below) i am unsure what you mean by No that is disorder  display - note that I am brand new to this HTML and CSS